# Option value unable to set dynamically

Tags: html, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to dynamically set the options tag by using the data from table.
This is my code.

```
 Select Branch:-<select name="codes">
            <%
            while(r.next()){
    %>
           <option value="<%=r.getString("code")%>"><%=r.getString("code")%></option>
            <%
           }
r.close();
s.close();
con.close();
    %>
        </select>
```

When i am not adding the value of option it is working fine but when i add the value of option it gives me am exception.
Please help

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it worked when you only fetched the string once, try doing it this way:

```
<%
  while(r.next()) {
    String codeValue = r.getString("code");
%>
<option value="<%=codeValue%>"><%=codeValue%></option>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not that big on JSP, and from your code I think it *should* have worked.